# could not connect to server /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, homebrew

I uninstalled and reinstalled `psql` and restarted my computer because someone suggested it. However I am still getting this error when I run `psql`

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I changed permissions as well. All I see in `/usr/local/var/postgres` is server.log.

```
postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

I am trying to run localhost for my rails app but I get this error as well.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75214/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory
take a look here! ;)

Comment: OS X, with Homebrew, right?